# Proof of subordination principle for holomorphic functions on $\mathbb{D}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, conformal-geometry, cauchy-integral-formula

I am trying to prove a very simple theorem that uses the general idea in complex analysis that if $f:\mathbb{D}\to\mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic, then the quantity $|f'(0)|$ is somehow responsible for how 'wide' the image $f(\mathbb{D})$ is.

In particular, I've got this:

**Claim:** Let $f,\,g:\mathbb{D}\to\mathbb{C}$ be injective holomorphic functions such that $g(0)=0=f(0)$ and $g(\mathbb{D})$ is a strict subset of $f(\mathbb{D})$. Then $|g'(0)| < |f'(0)|$.

I have written the following proof:

Since $g(\mathbb{D})\subset f(\mathbb{D})$ and both images contain the origin, it follows by Cauchy's integral formula that 
\begin{align*}
|g'(0)| &= \frac{1}{2\pi}\left|\int_{\partial \mathbb{D}} \frac{g(z)}{z^2}\,\text{d}z \right|\\
&< \frac{1}{2\pi}\left|\int_{\partial \mathbb{D}} \frac{f(z)}{z^2}\,\text{d}z \right|\\
&= |f'(0)|. 
\end{align*}

I am trying to use the fact that since $f$ and $g$ are conformal (injective and holomorphic), the curve $f(\partial \mathbb{D})$ is going to enclose $g(\partial \mathbb{D})$ around the origin. I think that this is correct, and I wouldn't have any serious doubts if it weren't for the fact that Duren (in *Univalent functions*) calls this a corollary of Schwarz's lemma, which I haven't used.

I think that I haven't had to use Schwarz's lemma because I've simplified the statement quite a bit to suit the application I need it for (Duren doesn't say that $f$ and $g$ both fix the origin, and only requires $f$ to be conformal).

But it would set my mind at ease if it could be confirmed that I haven't overlooked something.

Comment: Why *exactly* do you think that such an inequality between the two integrals holds?

Comment: Well $z^2$ has modulus 1 on that contour, so we can forget about it, and the length of $f(\partial\mathbb{D})$ is certainly greater than the length of $g(\partial\mathbb{D})$ because, as I say, the first curve encloses the other. I'm a little rusty on basic complex analysis, but this seems correct?

Comment: Even if you assume that $f$ and $g$ are defined on the boundary: You cannot compare the absolute value of two integrals by estimating the absolute value of the integrands.

Comment: I'm sorry, I see the error. My claim about the lengths doesn't necessarily hold just because the image of $g$ is contained in the image of $f$. Could the integral be interpreted as the area of the image, though? In that case it would be OK.

Comment: No, I see that this would never work, actually. My proof is totally wrong.

Comment: Note that Schwarz lemma is precisely the subordination principle when $f(z)=z$ (as $g$ is not required to be injective in the definition of subordination, but you are required to have $g(0)=f(0), g(D) \subset f(D), f$ injective since otherwise it's easy to give counterexamples), so one can think of the subordination principle as a generalization of Schwarz lemma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Consider the holomorphic function $h=f^{-1}\circ g.$ This is well defined since $g(\mathbb D)\subset f(\mathbb D).$ We have $h:\mathbb D\to \mathbb D$ and $h(0)=0.$ That should ring some bells.

Comment: Of course --  a simple trick and a neat solution. Thanks.